# How to check for notification in Watch kit OS2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, notifications, watchkit

I have a static and dynamic notification interface in watchkitOS2 and i need to check it in the simulator for now Xcode 7.2 . I refered through several documents but they initiate for making a new scheme for notification. I made but i cannot find the same in xcode. The screenshot here is

[ScreenShot for watchckit scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVQLz.png)

[Carousal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPfMG.png)

Comment: You need to run the project scheme of Notification for Watch app.

Comment: I did the same but it is not launching... It is showing carousal failed to launch  ... @RajanBalana

Comment: See the updated screen ..This is the error which i am getting @RajanBalana